# how to redirect on specific page using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, location

I am having trouble redirecting from one page to another on button click using javascript?

say, for example, one page is `index.php` and another is `sub-page.php`, how can I redirect to the subpage from the home page using javascript? can anyone please guide me? files are located in the root directory of my project.

I had already tried following code but it is not working :

HTML code :

```
<button type="button" onclick="test()">click me</button>
```

js code :

```
function test(){
 window.location.href = "./sub-page.php";
}
```

Comment: Please be more descriptive than just "not working". What actually happens?  Is `sub-page.php` located in the document root or under some sub folder?

Comment: Maybe the path to the sub-page.php is not right. You can also use `window.open("sub-page.php", "_self")`;

Comment: _Why_ would you want to abuse a button, for what is clearly a link’s job?

Answer (score 4):

You Can use this .

```
<script>window.location.href = "/sub-page.php";</script>

<script>window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

window.location.href = "sub-page.php";

Answer (score 3):

First check for the right path for the `sub-page` You can also use `window.open`.

```
function test(){
    window.open("sub-page.php", "_self")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is there any error in the browser's console?

If not, what you can do is put some "console.log" messages within your function, like

```
function test(){
 console.log("before href");
 window.location.href = "./sub-page.php";
 console.log("after href");
}
```

That way, you can tell if your function is being called correctly, by looking at the console output.

Always try to at least find an error message, instead of just saying it is not working. We will not be able to help you much with just a "not working".